# How to decide if $Q(\underline u,\underline v) $ on $\mathbb R^2$ is inner product or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-functions

How to decide if $Q(\underline u,\underline v) $ on $\mathbb R^2$ is inner product or not if $$ (\underline u, \underline v) = \underline u^T A\underline v$$ where $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
     -1 & -3 \\
5& 8 \\  
     \end{pmatrix}$$

Can this be opposed by considering the symmetric property only? 
$$ (\underline v, \underline u) = \underline v^T A\underline u \neq\underline u^T A\underline v$$
How to prove this?

Comment: The answer to your first question is yes. By the second question do you mean how to prove that symmetry does not hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $Q$ will NOT be an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ iff ANY of the properties of inner product does not hold:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

(Where in this case, the conjugate symmetry is just symmetry)

So if you show that ANY of this properties doesn't hold, say the symmetry, then $Q$ is NOT an inner product; as you said.

If you don't know how to do that, it's like this:

Since the property says that $Q(u,v)=Q(v,u)$ for **any pair** $u,v\in\mathbb{R}^2$; it's enough to show that there **exists** a particular pair $u_0,v_0$ such that  $Q(u_0,v_0)\neq Q(v_0,u_0)$ .

So just take  $$ u_0= (1,0) \ \ v_0=(0,1)$$

Then $Q(u_0,v_0)=-3\neq 5 = Q(v_0,u_0)$

In general, any $Q$ of the form $ Q(u,v)=u^TAv$ is an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^n \Leftrightarrow A\ $  is symmetric and positive-definite(which in the $\mathbb{R}^2$ case is equivalent to $det(A)\geq 0 \wedge \ a_{11}\geq 0$ ) .

Comment: That's NOT an inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you are taking only 1 vector...